# Extjs 4.2 grid groupHeaderTpl Issue

Tags: c#-4.0, extjs4.2

How can I get the total count of Group in ExtJS 4.2 grid with grouping feature which also has pagination implemented.

The counts for a Group do not reflect the total for that group but rather the number for that group that will fit on the page. In the above example I have a Grouping that is several hundred records in length. I have the page set for 50, so it shows 50. If I set the page for 10, it shows 10. If I set it for 20, it will show 20.

But, I would want the heading to show the total number for the group without regard to the pagination (records per page).

The code I have implemented for count is:

```
 var groupingFeature = Ext.create('Ext.grid.feature.Grouping', {
            groupHeaderTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
             '{columnName}:{name}, [Total: {[this.countTotal(values.rows)]}]',
                '', {
                    countTotal: function (records) {
                        var totalSum = 0;
                        totalSum = records.length;
                        return totalSum;
                    }
                }
            ),
            onLayout: function () {
                Ext.get(this.innerHd).setStyle("float", "none");
                this.scroller.setStyle("overflow-x", "scroll");
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for total number of items in each group, then you can use the following :

```
groupHeaderTpl: ['{columnName}: {name} ({children.length}) ']
```